# flutter , how to set image network as wallpaper 2021

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, wallpaper

I am working on an application to set wallpapers, which comes to the application through the link "**imgUrl**", but when I want to set a specific image as **wallpaper** it gives me this error,

`[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods)`

I hope you will give me an easy way to set an image as a wallpaper and also a way to save the image inside the device,
Note: I am using flutter for ***Android only***

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_downloader/image_downloader.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:wallpaper/wallpaper.dart';

class ImgDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImgDetailsState createState() => _ImgDetailsState();
}

class _ImgDetailsState extends State<ImgDetails> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
 
  var imgPath  ;

  String home = "Home Screen",
      lock = "Lock Screen",
      both = "Both Screen",
      system = "System";
 
  String _title = Get.arguments['title'];
  String _imgUrl = Get.arguments['url'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(_title),
      duration: const Duration(seconds:3),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text(_title),
      centerTitle: true,   
      ),
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: double.infinity,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              maxScale: 6,
              child: FadeInImage(
                image: NetworkImage(_imgUrl),
                placeholder: AssetImage('assets/img/img_ot_found.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.08,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  colors: [Colors.purple , Colors.purpleAccent]
              )
          ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.save_alt_rounded , color: Colors.white,size: 32), onPressed: (){
                  }),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.imagesearch_roller, color: Colors.white,size: 32), onPressed: (){
                  
                    _modal();
                  }),
                  IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.white,size: 32,), onPressed: (){

                    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                  }),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _askPermission() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    
      await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([
        PermissionGroup.storage,
        PermissionGroup.camera,
        PermissionGroup.location,
      ]);
    } else {
      await PermissionHandler()
          .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage);
    }
  }

  _modal() {
    showModalBottomSheet(

        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2),
        elevation: 0,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30,)),
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 130,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                )
            ),

            child: Column(

              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                _createTile(context, 'Home Screen', Icons.home, _action1),
                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                _createTile(context, 'Lock Screen', Icons.lock, _action2),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  ListTile _createTile(BuildContext context, String name, IconData icon,
      Function action) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(icon,
        color: Colors.blueAccent,),
      title: Text(name,
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 20),),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        action();
      },
    );
  }

  _action1() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await _askPermission();
    }
    var response = await Dio()
        .get(_imgUrl, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
    //await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.data));
    home = await Wallpaper.homeScreen(_imgUrl);
    final result = home = home;
    print(result);
  }

  _action2() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await _askPermission();
    }
    var response = await Dio()
        .get(_imgUrl, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
    //await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(response.data));
    home = await Wallpaper.lockScreen(_imgUrl);
    final result = home = lock;
    print(result);
  }
     

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having a problem with the permission. You need to add a permission code to the AndroidManifest file. Can you send me all the error logs so I can figure out what privilege is missing?